# PHP: Parse XML with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having issues attempting to parse an XML file I'm pulling in from another site with SimpleXML. I need to display the rent for certain properties. However, I only want to display the rent for certain properties. I've never seen an XML file structured in this manner: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1925679/example.xml

First, how would I parse through this file based on

```
Property->PropertyID->MITS:Identification->MITS:PrimaryID
```

Then, echo out the `Property->Floorplan->MarketRent(Min and Max)` based on an ID?

TIA!!!!

Comment: are you thrown off by the namespaces ("MITS:")? If so, don't worry about them, just treat the whole thing ("MITS:CompanyInfo") as a node name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get all properties
$properties = $xml->xpath('//Property');

// get document namesapces in prefix => uri format
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);


foreach($properies as $property)
{
   // get namespaced nodes
   $identification = $property->PropertyID->children($namespaces['MITS']);
   $id = $identification->children($namespaces['MITS'])->PrimaryID;

   // do your check id is an expected value or whatever and if so then...

   foreach($property->Floorplan as $floorplan){
   {
      echo $floorplan->MarketRent['min'];
      echo $floorplan->MarketRent['max'];
   }
}
```

You could probably com up with an xpath query to ONLY select properties with a given id or set of ids straight away so then you would only have to loop over them and invoke the floorplan loop but ill leave that to your investigation :-) I will say though if you go that route, you will need to register the namespaces with xpath i think. Pretty sure thats not automatic.

Comment: This worked perfectly! The only change I had to make was $xml->getNamespaces(true); Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem! Glad you worked it out. Will update answer with your adjustment for others' benefit :-)